# Count workers in business with branches

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, count

Select a group, where is one **Main** and for example `5` **Branch**. So, the total of places is `6`. In each of those `6`, search for `3` workers, who is working as `job_types LIKE "%C%"`. If, in one of those `6` places, are `3`workers with given parameter, query must get results of all those `6` places.

**To clarify:** `3` workers must be working in same main/branch.

Because project itself is very dificult, it would be better, to get results using **RAW** query:

**business table**

```
id     |    mainorbranch    |    name
--------------------------------------
1           Main                 Apple
2           Branch               Apple London
3           Branch               Apple Manchester
4           Main                 IBM
5           Branch               IBM London
etc ...
```

**Relationship**

**business_branches table**

```
b_id     |    branch_id    |    id
--------------------------------------
1             1                 1
2             2                 1
3             3                 1
4             4                 4
5             5                 4
// etc
```

**people_details table**

```
d_id     |    id    |    job_types
--------------------------------------
1             1          C
2             3          D
3             2          F
4             4          C
5             5          C
// etc
```

**people_branches table**

```
pb_id     |    branch_id    |    id
--------------------------------------
1              1                 3
2              3                 2
3              4                 4
4              2                 5
5              1                 1
// etc
```

**What i need to get:**

```
Business id    |    Name    |    Postcode
-----------------------------------------
1                   Apple        postcode
2                   Apple 232    postcode
3                   Apple 323    postcode
// etc...
```

---

DB Structure for Helpers
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/206733

[Simplified, minified SQL file with total of 110k+ rows](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnzklo6gi60p3vv/vetfiledbf%20%281%29.sql?dl=0)

**UPDATE**

Answer by **@KikiTheOne** is kinda working, but it gets only half a results. Other half is missing.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost here.

Comment: This question is tagged with Laravel; are you expecting help in Query Builder, or Eloquent? If you are not, should probably remove Laravel tag.

Comment: @RichardHousham for example, there is a group of 1 main and 3 branches. Search for 3 ``"%C%"`` in each of 4 places. If ``true``, display all info of those 4 places. (1main, 3 branches).

Comment: @JofryHS minute please.

Comment: @JofryHS question is updated.

Comment: Try giving some examples query inputs (i.e. the query parameters into the method that will query the database), and expected results. Also with explanation why those expected results are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as discussed in Chat. here is a solution:

if u Need Company Infos... get them @ t1.XXXX like `postcode`.

i changed

```
"pb_id" "branch_id" "id"
"1" "1" "3"
"2" "3" "2"
"3" "1" "4"
"4" "1" "5"
"5" "1" "1"
```

so i get 3 People in 1 branch

```
SELECT 
    t1.id as "Business id",
    t1.name as Name,
    'postcode' as "Postcode" 
FROM SO_business as t1 inner join 
(
    SELECT * FROM SO_busness_branches as t3 
    inner join 
    (
        SELECT 
            t5.branch_id as inner_branch,
            count(t5.branch_id) as workers_in,
            max(t6.job_types) as job_types,
            max(t7.id) as mainbranch
        FROM 
            SO_people_branches as t5
                inner join SO_people_details as t6
                    on t5.id = t6.id 
                inner join SO_busness_branches as t7 
                    on t5.branch_id = t7.branch_id 
        WHERE 
            t6.job_types LIKE '%C%' 
        GROUP BY 
            t5.branch_id
    ) as t4
        on t3.id = t4.inner_branch 
    WHERE t4.workers_in >= 3
) as t2 
    on t1.id = t2.branch_id
```

Explanation:

-.1  the Most inner SQL Counts ALL branches with workers ( number of workers init ) and Job_type = %c% and joines the MAIN id of the branch.

-.2 the second SQL gets that info and only selects all branches with workers >= 3

-.3 the outer SQL selects all inner INFOS and gives back ALL branches/main with the branchID-Main from the Inner SQL. AND connects them to the Business table so u can Display all Infos likepostcode from there

Answer (score 1):

hope that this works as it's not as easy to interpret the relationships with the name of the columns in your question.

With this script you can add any group of main/branch to search into

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, 'postcode' as postcode 
FROM business b
INNER JOIN business_branches bb ON (bb.branch_id = b.id)
WHERE bb.id IN (
  SELECT bb1.id FROM people_details pd
  INNER JOIN people_branches pb ON (pb.id = pd.id)
  INNER JOIN business_branches bb1 ON (bb1.branch_id = pb.branch_id)
  INNER JOIN business b1 ON (b1.id = bb1.branch_id)
  WHERE
  pd.job_types like '%C%' AND
  bb1.id IN (1,4) -- You can add as many group of businesses (main/branch combinations) using the main branch key
  GROUP BY pb.branch_id HAVING count(pb.branch_id) >= 3
)
```